# How to add custom protocol to Vista "Set Associations" list?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, registry, protocols

I've registered custom protocol "xyz" on Windows Vista:

```
HKEY\_CLASSES\_ROOT\xyz = "URL:Extensions Protocol"
```

It works OK with my application.

Open **"Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Set Associations"**, scroll the list to the end. Here is the list of protocols. 
I would like to see my custom protocol associated with my application.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find the extension you are looking for in the `Set Associations`, then first open `Command` prompt and type

```
assoc .abc=
```

where *.abc* is the extension you want to associate. This will add the extension (in this example .abc) to the list of extensions in Set Associations. Then choose the program you want to use for opening files of that type in Set Associations. 
I haven't tested myself if this works for protocols as well but I don't see any reasons why it wouldn't.